# Operator '<' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String'

Tags: java, android

i got the system time in a string for example something like "1240".
then i wanted to do something like if the system time was < than 1240,then close the application.
but it gives me the "Operator '<' cannot be applied to java.lang.String!" Error!

My code is :

```
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    TextView txtCurrentTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showtime);
                    Date dt = new Date();
                    int hours = dt.getHours();
                    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                    int mynum = 1240;
                    String curTime = hours + "" + minutes;
                    txtCurrentTime.setText(curTime);
                    if(curTime < mynum ){
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        });
```

What's the problem?

Comment: is "hello"<"world" true? or false?

Comment: Operator '<' cannot be applied to java.lang.String! That is the problem

Comment: Note the error test: Operator '<' cannot be applied to java.lang.String".  This means that the '<' operator can not be applied to an object of type java.lang.String.

This is Java, not clownlanguage.

Consider browsing to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ and reading"Learning the Java Language"

Comment: convert the string to a non-string, perhaps an int or a long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

< is not defined for a string and an int of course . So you can't use it .

your current time can be calculated like this :

```
int curTime = 100*hours + minutes;
```

then you can use < between two integers.

I believe though you must use System Milliseconds which is more usual.

Comment: Can't use System Milliseconds unless you want to do timezone offsetting yourself.

Answer (score 3):

try{

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
 String str1 = String.valueOf(hours1) + ":" + String.valueOf(minutes1) + ":" + "00";
 String str2 = String.valueOf(hours2) + ":" + String.valueOf(minutes2) + ":" + "00";
 Date date1 = formatter.parse(str1);
 Date date2 = formatter.parse(str2);

 if (date1.compareTo(date2)<0)
  {
    //       if date2 > date1                
  }

}catch (ParseException e1){
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

[formats for dates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

check date/time format as per your requirement from here

Comment: How is that a help when OP tried to compare `"1620" < 1240`, i.e. hours and minutes, not day/month/year?

Comment: create a string by appending hours and minute in "H:mm" format then use simpledateformat to parse it into date and compare. i provided a reference for Pattern supported by simpledateformat

Comment: An answer is much more useful if it is tailored to the question, rather than just being a boilerplate answer. In this case, that would mean to make the code format hours and minutes, not day/month/year, because the question is not about dates, it's about times. This answer is even a bad boilerplate answer, with that dumb `catch` clause at the end, since dumping stacktrace and continuing execution as if nothing went bad is a really bad example to make.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(hours * 100 + minutes < mynum){
    System.exit(0);
}
```